# Make WPF Tabcontrol Header Stack Vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have been trying to make my tabcontrol header stack up vertically, but no matter what I do it won't just work properly

This is what I want:[image]

Its funny because this display is as a result of some error from Visual Studio Editor.

But this is what I get

[image]

I Tried this code

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Prepare Report"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Print PDF"></MenuItem>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Exit"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Configurations">
            <MenuItem Header="Pay Grade"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Staff Levels"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Departments"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Authroizations"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Help">
            <MenuItem Header="Help Content"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="About Software"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{DynamicResource NavigationMenu}" Margin="20 0">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-360" />
                                </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem x:Name="Dashboard">
            <TabItem.Header><TextBlock Text="DASHBOARD" FontSize="20" ></TextBlock></TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem  x:Name="Staffs">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="STAFFS" ></TextBlock>
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem  x:Name="Departments">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="DEPARTMENTS" ></TextBlock>
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="Settings">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="SETTINGS" ></TextBlock>
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

But it breaks my UI and displays like this

[image: Dark Shade Added]
 The Dark part is not supposed to be there, I do not even know where it is coming from

Comment: why -360? Should be +270...

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to solve this by removing your data template / style, and simply by setting the `TabStripPlacement` property of the `TabControl` to `Left`

Or via a style setter, something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TabControl">
    <Setter Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"></Setter>
</Style>
```

The **default** TabStrip (actually a TabPanel) is simply a StackPanel within a template. The TabStripPlacement changes the location of the TabStrip within the TabControl - but also switches the StackPanel from Horizontal to Vertical orientation ... which should give you result you're looking for.

Comment: OK, well I think you need to give us some more information then. Show us the XAML for the TabControl itself, and any other styling or templates you're using. Your problems is a bit hard to diagnose from the snippet you've posted.

Comment: JamesOkpeGeorge, @olitee's answer is the correct one. You must have some extra baggage going on. Try starting fresh in a test project with a simple tabcontrol with the default style and the `TabStripPlacementvalue` set to left. You should be able to replicate his results.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following gives you an idea of how your requirements can be accomplished. The basic idea is to switch from TabPanel to a StackPanel in the TabControl style, don't any Background colors and rotate the header in the TabItem style.

```
<Window x:Class="ShowScroller.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="421">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                        <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFAAAAAA" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                              Grid.Column="1"
                                              Margin="0"
                                              ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                            <StackPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Margin="0,0,4,-1"
                                        Panel.ZIndex="1"
                                        Background="Transparent"
                                        IsItemsHost="True"
                                        KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" />
                            <Border x:Name="Border"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    CornerRadius="2"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Root">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF0000FF" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="Border"
                                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                    BorderBrush="Gainsboro"
                                    BorderThickness="0,0,2,0" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="12,10,12,10" Text="{TemplateBinding Header}">
                                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform />
                                        <SkewTransform />
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                        <TranslateTransform />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Width="391"
                    Height="324"
                    Margin="49,43,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TabItem FontSize="20"
                     Header="TabItem"
                     RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Grid Background="#FFF5E5E5">
                    <TextBlock Margin="55,107,0,0"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                               Text="TextBlock 1"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5F5">
                    <TextBlock Margin="54,98,0,0"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                               Text="TextBlock 2"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFEBF5E5">
                    <TextBlock Margin="54,98,0,0"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                               Text="TextBlock 3"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```